# How can we determine the target (lightning__HomePage, lightning__Tab an LWC is placed on?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

I am new to LWC development. I was wondering if there is a way we can determine which target (lightningCommunity__Page, lightning__tab etc..)  the control is placed on, in the js file of the component?  When a button on the control is clicked, it should bring up a community page if the control is on a community page, or if it is on a tab, it should bring up a tab page.
Ex: something like this

```
handleNewUser(){
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](
        // if the control is placed on a community page  -> for external users
            {
            type: "comm__namedPage",
            attributes: {
                name: 'New_User__c'
            }
        }
       // else if the control is placed on a tab page ->  for internal users
        {
            type: "standard__navItemPage",
            attributes: {
               apiName: 'MyCustomTabName'
            }
       );
    }
```

Comment: I'm not certain if it can be detected programmatically but if it is not possible, you could implement a workaround [using this concept](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_object_context) and set a property in your component to a known value based on the `targetConfig` context that you can check later at runtime.

Comment: Another option is to make an apex call to determine if logged in user is community user or not, then use that flag to perform appropriate redirection.

Comment: It won't let me create <property> tag for  <targetConfig targets="lightning__Tab"> and targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Page">, so I can't check for a variable. It works for <targetConfig targets="lightning__HomePage"> but I want to place the control in a Tab and a Community page

Comment: What I ended up doing was to put the component in an App page and add the following to the js-meta.xml
<targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__AppPage">
            <property label="source" name="source" type="String" default="App Page" />
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
and added these lines to the .js file
@api source;
if ( this.source == 'App Page')
       {
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__navItemPage',
                attributes: {
                    apiName: 'App_Page'
                }     });  }